# Expectation of e^(cX) if X is a geometric Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

(Edit:) *The short version*: Calculate $$E[e^{cY}]$$ if $c < 0$ and $Y$ is lognormally distributed, i.e. $\log(Y) \sim N(\tilde\mu, \tilde\sigma^2)$.

*The long version*:
I want to calculate
$$E[e^{cX_T} \mid X_t = x]$$
for $c < 0$, where $X$ is a geometric Brownian motion, i.e.
$$dX_t = rX_tdt + \sigma X_t dW_t$$
for $r \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma > 0$ and a Brownian motion $W$.

My ideas so far:

(i) If $X_t = x$, then $X_T = x e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t) + \sigma (W_T-W_t)}$ is log-normally distributed, so the expecation is
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma\sqrt{T-t}} \int_0^\infty e^{cy} \frac{1}{y} e^{-\frac{(\log(y/x) - (r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t))^2}{2\sigma^2(T-t)}}dy.$$
But I do not really know what to do with this expression.

(ii) Itô:
$$ \begin{align} de^{cX_t} &= ce^{cX_t} dX_t + \frac{c^2}{2} e^{cX_t} d[X]_t\\ &= ce^{cX_t} dX_t + \frac{c^2}{2} e^{cX_t} \sigma^2 X_t^2 dt\\ &= (crX_t + \frac{1}{2} c^2 \sigma^2 X_t^2) e^{cX_t}dt + c \sigma X_t dW_t.\end{align}.$$
Again, I am stuck.

Does anyone have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: Have you come across moment generating functions?

Comment: See the solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876317/exponential-of-squared-brownian-motion#comment1807790_876317)

Comment: If $c > 0$, the expectation above is indeed the moment-generating function of the lognormal distribution.
Unfortunately, that function does not exist (i.e. the expectation is infinity). For $c < 0$, I could not find any calculations on Google.

Comment: Ilya, thank you for the link!
I am not really sure how to apply this to my problem, as I have to work with $X_t = x \exp(... + \sigma W_t)$ and not $W_t$ directly.

Comment: @EliasStrehle Do you want to calculate the expectation or the *conditional* expectation?

Comment: As long as $T$ can be chosen arbitrary, that does not really matter, if I am not mistaken.
X is a time-homogenous Markov process, so if $X_t = x > 0$, then $$E[f(X_T) \mid \mathcal{F_t}] = E[f(X_T) \mid X_t = x] = E[f(X_{T-t}) \mid X_0 = x] = v(x)$$ for a function $v$, correct?

Comment: The left-hand side is a *random variable* whereas the right-hand side is a deterministic value. This equality does not hold.

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course. 
My notation is very sloppy. $Y_t = E[f(X_T) \mid \mathcal{F}_t]$ _is_ a random variable. But the value of $Y_t$ only depends on the value of $X_t$ (this follows from the Markov property; we can disregard all information that is contained in $\mathcal{F}_t$, except for the information what $X_t$ is).
This is why we can write $Y_t = v(X_t)$ here. In the equations above I merely assumed that $X_t = x$.